# ColdFusion Dynamic Drop Down List

Tags: coldfusion

I am looking to code a dynamic drop down list within ColdFusion. What I want is the drop down list to be populated by the above drop down list (example: Select Province (B.C) will populate the City drop down list with all cities within that Province). Province data will be collected from a ColdFusion query and same with the city's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use CFSELECT binding them with cfc's.

Here's an example:

```
<cfform name="mycfform">
  <!--- 
    The States selector. 
    The bindonload attribute is required to fill the selector. 
  --->
  <cfselect name="state" bind="cfc:bindFcns.getstates()" bindonload="true">
      <option name="0">--state--</option>
  </cfselect>
  <cfselect name="city" bind="cfc:bindFcns.getcities({state})">
      <option name="0">--city--</option>
  </cfselect>
</cfform>
```

The {state} in the second bind is the value of the first CFSELECT.  By using CFC's it will repopulate the second select each time the first changes.

Comment: How would I use the <CF Query with the bind?

Comment: Well you wouldnt directly on your page, you would want to create a cfc and use cfselect to call the function. If you take a look at the CF Docs for cfselect, in example 2 towards the bottom it gives you all the code for a working example. Set it up and play with it.  Here is the link: [link]http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7afe.html